# Adjusting table using float left and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a year calendar. In the year view the user will be presented with all the months of the year, kinda like (kinda....) the ical year view. My code is in [bootply](http://bootply.com/95068)
.(I cannot enter the code here cause it exceeds the character limit).

Why does some months not appear correctly. Julyfor example floats right....Am I doing something wrong?Most of the months are placed correctly but three of them aren't. Is it the height?

Comment: Yes, you have to fix a value for the height.. Try with `height: 175px;`

Comment: Could you explain to me please if possible why i had to do that?Shouldn't each table float to the left and let height fix itself?And why did you choose 175px for height?And its fixxed but i can't green light your comment i think.

Comment: No, if you want to get your elements aligned well you have to set the same value for the width and the height. If you don't Look at the months : "may" and "june" they have different height because "May" have more days than "June" and that will push the "August" month in the bottom left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add fixed height to the tables you will solve that float but table cells will have different height then because some tables (months) have more rows (weeks) then other. You could try putting every 3 tables in a div with clear: both;.

[bootply](http://bootply.com/95076)

Comment: Should the div have fixed height?

Answer (score 0):

Try using bootstrap ui with angularjs.
There is a easy datepicker.
Check [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)